# Ubuntu 14.04 keeps turning back on after a suspend command

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management

So I've tried closing the computer lid, but as soon as it seems to have suspended (mouse lights off, etc), I heard the sound of the fan and the computer turned on again by itself.

I tried using sudo pm-suspend and it turned itself back on after a second.

Is there a way I can check what's causing the system to turn itself back on?